# Fechar sweetalert2 ao achar os dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Eu gostaria que ao achar os dados o sweetalert2 fechasse o modal.

Mas ele não retorna nada no .then

Eis meu código:

```
swal({
            title: 'Auto close alert!',
            html: 'I will close in <strong></strong> seconds.',

            onOpen: () => {
                var ano = $('.slt-ano').val()
                swal.showLoading()
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                })
               return  $.ajax({
                    url : '{{ route('medicao.getDadosToGrapsh') }}',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        ano : ano
                    }

                }).done((r)=>{
                    return r
                })

            },

        }).then((result) => {
            console.log( result )
            if (
                // Read more about handling dismissals
                result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer
            ) {
                console.log('I was closed by the timer')
            }
        })
```

Como faço para retornar os dados no .then para fechar o modal?

Answer (score 2):

Descobri!

Caso alguém necessite, eis o código

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alerta()
})

function alerta(){
  swal({
    title: 'Auto close alert!',
    html: 'I will close in <strong></strong> seconds.',
      onOpen: () => {
         swal.showLoading()
      }
   })

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Terminou o processo, fechar sweetalert2')
    swal.close()
  }, 3000);
  

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.25.6/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.25.6/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

O que eu fiz?

Deixei a sweetalert2 carregando enquanto fazia o processo de pegar as informações

```
swal({
    title: 'Auto close alert!',
    html: 'I will close in <strong></strong> seconds.',
      onOpen: () => {
         swal.showLoading()
      }
   })
```

Pegou as informações, mandei fechar

```
swal.close()
```

Comment: Show de bola...

Answer (score 0):

Já conferiu se está chegando algo no `result`?

E `.then` quer dizer: Oque será executado AO fechar, seja clicando no botão de ok ou de cancelar, para fechar um modal vc deve chamar o método hide.

Trate o sucesso e error do Ajax,

```
sucess: function(data){ /* essa função não trata especificamente o dado, ela apenas retorna ou não se o Ajax conseguiu fazer o envio/request da solicitação*/
    if(data == “exe”) {// se data for igual que vc espera ou deseja
        $(“idModal”).close(); // então fecha o modal ou .hide();
    }
}
```

Veja um [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/MGbXk/) de um fechamento de Modal

Comment: Sim. No result so retorna o objeto `"dismiss" : true`

Comment: E nesse caso estou usando o sweetalert